# Add dropdownlist value to database which items add from page load functions

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //skipped
    foreach(pair item in al)  
    {           
        pid.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.getTitle(), item.getId()));

    }  

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
            insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parent_id", Convert.ToInt32(pid.SelectedValue));

}
```

From the above code there is a dropdownlist that all items are added from Page_Load function, and the bug is that, whatever items i choose from dropdownlist, only the first item is added to database.

anyone know what's the problem?

thanks!

Comment: i did't got you correctly , but are you trying to say that data has been populated in dropdownlist but when you select some item and click on a button you only get the first item of the list rather then the selected item.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not add items during postbacks

try

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    foreach(pair item in al)  
    {           
        pid.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.getTitle(), item.getId()));

    }  
}
```

The [IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx) property checks whether the page is being rendered for the first time or is responding to a postback.